# Error in update time elementry os

Tags: release-hera, updates

> Err:12 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt
>   YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE-pgdg Release              404  Not Found [IP:
>   "myip"]
>
> E: The repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt
>   YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE-pgdg Release' does not have a Release file.
>
> N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is
>   therefore disabled by default.
>
> N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for
>
> repository creation and user configuration details.

Answer (score 0):

You have somehow added PPA's without changing the text **YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE-pgdg**. remove that lines and add **bionic** instead. Or complete remove them from the sourcelist.

You can find the file on postgresql in /etc/apt/sources.list.d and delete/edit it.

Answer (score 0):

try [this](http://elementaryosguides.com/2020/06/05/failed-to-fetch-updates/) guide, probably it's what your looking for.